# HTML "readonly" input value can be edit when checked a check box

Tags: html, checkbox, input

I have a input `<input type="text" value="1" readonly id='aaa'/>`.

I would like to give it a function when user check the box then can edit the value of `id=aaa`.

Sample:

```
<input type="text" value="1" readonly/> <input type="checkbox" /> Checked this if you want to edit the value.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Give appropriate Id to check box and use below code :

if($("#CheckboxId").is(":checked"))
{
    $("#aaa").removeAttr("readonly");
    
}else{
  $("#aaa").attr("readonly","readonly");
}

Answer (score 1):

You want to use JavaScript to change the `readOnly` property. Set it to the opposite of whether the checkbox is checked.

```js
document.getElementById('checksome').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var changeThis = document.getElementById('readsome');

  changeThis.readOnly = !this.checked;
});
```

```html
<input id="readsome" type="text" value="1" readonly>
<label><input id="checksome" type="checkbox"> Click this to edit</label>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have chosen the `click` event instead of the `change` event? I toggled the checkbox using the keyboard and to my surprise this also triggers the `click` event in Chrome.

Comment: @dehart In FF, too. (That's about everybody these days!) Not really; just because OP said click, and I know click is consistent, so I did the same. (Fuzzy memory of some problem with change event, but no idea where/when from.)

Answer (score 1):

Add an onchange event to the checkbox that changes to readOnly attribute of its previous sibling (the textfield)

```
<input type="text" value="1" readonly id="aaa" />
<input type="checkbox" onchange="getElementById('aaa').readOnly = !this.checked" />
Checked this if you want to edit the value.
```

Comment: +1 b/c, as you have it, `readOnly` should be linked to `this.checked`, given the label text (instead of just toggling the `readOnly` state), which I've incorporated into my answer.